# PHP for to while

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop

hi guys im having a problem with php

i want to change a for statement to while

here is the code:

```
<?php
$i=1;
$uitkomst = 0;
$getal = 5;
echo "Het getal is $getal<br><br>";
echo "Het totaal van $i tot en met $getal is <br>";
echo "0";
for ($i = 1;$i <= $getal;$i++){
$uitkomst = $uitkomst + $i ;
echo "+ $i";
}
echo "= $uitkomst"
?>
```

what do i need to change ?

***EDIT: i fixed it by looking at your examples.***

***i need it for an assignment.***

***Thanks and***

***Greetings,***

***Darren Brown***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
for ($i = 1;$i <= $getal;$i++){
  $uitkomst = $uitkomst + $i ;
  echo "+ $i";
}
```

To this:

```
$i=1;
while($i <= $getal) {
  $uitkomst = $uitkomst + $i ;
  echo "+ $i";
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 1;$i <= $getal;$i++){
```

equals

```
$i = 1;
while  ($i <= $getal) {
    ...
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the Code for the while loop.

```
$i = 1;
while($i++ <= $getal){
    $uitkomst = $uitkomst + $i ;
    echo "+ $i";
}
```

But why do you need it as a while loop?